# How can I reuse the same table alignment specifications in many tables?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{$}c<{$}|>{$}c<{$}|}
     1 & 2 \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{$}c<{$}|>{$}c<{$}|}
    3 & 4 \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I am new to LaTeX.
I have a LaTeX file containing many large tables, each containing large number of columns.
All the tables have the same kind of columns, and need similar alignment and column widths.
I am looking for an easy way to specify a common alignment instruction for all of them (`|>{$}c<{$}|>{$}c<{$}|` in the above example). Is there a way to specify and reuse the string `|>{$}c<{$}|>{$}c<{$}|` (using `\newcommand` or `\let` or `\def` etc), so that I can easily replicate the behavior in all my tables?

Comment: \newcommand{\mytabs}{|>{$}c<{$}|>{$}c<{$}|} will reproduce the results, but without your    \usepackege I get a lot of errors either way.

Comment: Try \newenvironment

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to define a new column type and, for a large number of columns, exploit

```
*{<number>}{<col specs>}
```

Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{C|}}
1 & 2 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{C|}}
3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, I don't recommend “ruled tables”: a table is not a worksheet screen. Look at the [documentation of the `booktabs` package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) for some examples.

Answer (score 2):

A column type, defined by `\newcolumntype` of package `array` can cover more than one column. Furthermore it can take arguments, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{A}[1]{|*{#1}{>{$}c<{$}|}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{A{2}}
     1 & 2 \\
  \end{tabular}

  \bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{A{4}}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Since all of your tables would appear to contain math-mode material, you should consider switching from the `tabular` to the `array` environment. LaTeX `array` environments are supposed to be used in math-mode; their `l`, `c`, and `r` alignment specifiers work exactly as their counterparts in `tabular` environments do, except that because they're already in math mode, it's not necessary to resort to constructs such as `>{$}c<{$}`. The `\hline` and `\cline` commands work as expected in `array` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{A first table}
\[
  \begin{array}{|c|c|}
     \hline
     1 & 2 \\
     \hline
  \end{array}
\]
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{A second table}
\[  
  \begin{array}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    -3 & -4 \\
    \hline
  \end{array}
\]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

There's one other, fairly subtle difference between `tabular` and `array` environments: The default amount of intercolumn white space. These amounts are governed by the parameters `\arraycolsep` and `\tabcolsep`, whose default values are `5pt` and `6pt`, respectively. If you have lots of columns in a table, you might start to note the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how one can make the fixed part of your tables into an environment. There's one optional argument, the number of columns – 4 by default:

```
        \documentclass[12pt]{article}

         \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{array}

        \pagestyle{empty}
        \raggedbottom

        \newenvironment{mytable}[1][4]{%
        \begin{table}[!h]
        \centering\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
        \begin{tabular}{|*{#1}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
        \hline}%
        {\\\hline\end{tabular}
        \end{table}}%

        \begin{document}

        With the default number of columns:
        \begin{mytable}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        5 & 6 & 7 & 8
        \end{mytable}

        and with 10: 
        \begin{mytable}[10]
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4  & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  & 9  & 10\\
        2 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 11 & 13 & 17 & 19 & 23 & 29
        \end{mytable}

        \end{document}
```

[image]